# Can't scrape data from webpage with popup/frame

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, robotframework

I am having trouble finding elements on a customer-facing webpage that I am scraping data from, using Robot Framework + Selenium. My trouble, I think, has to do with the desired data existing in a popup/frame. The data I seek is located on a customer's invoice, which pops up when I press a button ("View Current Invoice"). I've been successful with logging into the site and navigating around, and at one point I was successful pressing the View Current Invoice button to cause the invoice to pop up - but forgot to commit that code and lost it. :-(

In any case, eve if I manually enter the popped up invoice by pressing the button when my script is expecting it to be pressed, I can't seem to scrape the subsequent data. I have tried to identify elements on the invoice using locators (from Right-Click-Inspect capability built into Firefox and Chrome; Katalaon Recorder; Selenium IDE; etc.). I get what looks like a valid locator (almost always Xpath); yet when I run my Robot script, it fails to find the element in question. I have spent a lot of time poring over the page's source code, but since I am not as savvy with HTML/JS/CSS as I should be, I haven't been successful.

Here is a screenshot of the invoice button:

[image]

And here is what I see when the button is pressed. I want to scrape all the invoice data, like Amount Due, Invoice Number, Due Date, etc.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what I am missing here? What would you do to get the data on the invoice if you were in my shoes? I know my question probably sounds vague and naiive, but I am at the end of my rope, so to speak. I am willing to share page source code, more screenshots, whatever is required.

**EDIT** I used Rahul Rai's method to inspect the popup while it was popped up; then searched for "iframe". There were 10 matches; #7, when clicked on, resulted in the invoice popup being highlighted in blue:

[image]

I assume this means this is the iframe referencing the popup? If so, I should be able to find information about the "handle" to the iframe in the inspection code, but I don't see anything there that matches the locators I am used to (e.g. name, id, xpath). I even tried "Select Frame    1599252503952", but that just resulted in a
"Element with locator '1599252503952' not found" error.

Comment: once you press view current invoice button and screen in loaded you want to scrape. Open in inspection mode > go to elements tab > do ctrlF > search for //iframe and check if any match is found . Also check if all the elements in opened invoice detailed page are inside that iframe ???

Comment: Try to select the popup with the Select Frame keyword from SeleniumLibrary http://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Select%20Frame.

Comment: @BenceKaulics - I had tried that before; the problem is I don't know what locator to use to uniquely specify the iframe in question.

Comment: @rahulrai, I used your method, and may have found the iframe specifying the popup. My OP is edited with that information...still can't get a handle on that pesky iframe!

Comment: @JeffWright Please see answer section, I have tried to scrape few data from above mentioned invoice. Note : Since you have not shared HTML code for elements you are trying to scrape, I am am doing sampling here, please implement and let me know if you are able to get complete solution based on it.

Comment: @rahulrai - I spent several hours today on this, and have gotten nowhere. I feel like I am lost in a forest. I am willing to share the HTML for elements, as you mentioned above - what is the method for getting this info? Right-click on main page or when invoice is popped up? HTML source? Frame source? They each seem to give different information. smh I think I am beignning to appreciate how complex modern web pages are...

Comment: @Jeff just open in inspection mode and copy the information inside elements tab and share. That’s it.

Comment: @rahulrai - here is the HTML which causes the invoice popup to be highlighted, using Inspect in Chrome...how to select this frame?    

<iframe frameborder="0" src="/cmc/invoice_detail_container.pyt?direction=//my.hughesnet.com/cmc/invoice_detail.pyt%3Finvnumber%1234-567890&amp;portletId=863" name="1599391562960" class="cboxIframe" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>

Comment: I figured it out! I will post as answer.

Comment: @JeffWright If above is the iframe then the code i have shared will be sufficient to switch to your frame. Happy you find a way. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was finally able to scrape data from the Invoice popup after inspecting the HTML source, and seeing this:

```
<iframe frameborder="0" src="/cmc/invoice_detail_container.pyt?direction=//my.hughesnet.com/cmc/invoice_detail.pyt%3Finvnumber%1234-567890&amp;portletId=863" name="1599391562960" class="cboxIframe" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" mozallowfullscreen="true"></iframe>
```

I was then able to use the Select Frame keyword in Robot Framework, specifying the iframe locator for the popup, using the 'class' strategy. I also had to explicitly select the main body frame first. In the end, the code that allowed me to enter the iframe and scrape was:

```
Select Frame    body
Select Frame    class:cboxIframe
```

Big thank you to Rahul Rai for pushing me closer to the solution; and thanks to the others who answered as well.

Answer (score 2):

As per above screen you have shared I can see your Invoice details are inside iframe. So after clicking on **View Current Invoice** button you can use below code to navigate inside frame and then scrape required information.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[contains(@src,'invoice_detail_container']")))
#Code to scrape data
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath('<xpath>')
print(ele.txt)
......
......
#After your work is done in this frame to navigate back to main window
driver.switch_to.default_content()
```

**Note:** I have assumed your main frame for invoice is not in side any other iframe ( Based on screen shared). Also before elements start there is no other nested frame. If there is any other nested frame you need to navigate first into that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch your site to frame/popup, you can use like below example, may be it will help you.

```
 IList<IWebElement> textfields = new List<IWebElement>();
 textfields = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("iframe"));
 driver.SwitchTo().Frame(textfields[count); // number of textfields list.
```

please try to implement as per your scenario, let me know if any question.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to do :

```
driver.switch_to_active_element()
```

and then scrape the popup to close it. Then I think it will be okay...